# make file.exists() case insensitive

Tags: r, case-insensitive, file-exists

I have a line of code in my script that checks if a file exists (actually, many files, this one line gets looped for a bunch of different files):

```
file.exists(Sys.glob(file.path(getwd(), "files", "*name*")))
```

This looks for any file in the directory /files/  that has "name" in it, e.g. "filename.csv". However, some of my files are named "fileName.csv" or "thisfileNAME.csv". They do not get recognized. How can i make file.exists treat this check in a case insensitive way?

In my other code i usually make any imported names or lists immediately lowercase with the **tolower** function. But I don't see any option to include that in the **file.exists** function.

Comment: Based on the `file.exists` docs, it looks like this is based on underlying OS-specific functions: "Case-insensitive file systems
Case-insensitive file systems are the norm on Windows and macOS, but can be found on all OSes (for example a FAT-formatted USB drive is probably case-insensitive).

These functions will most likely match existing files regardless of case on such file systems: however this is an OS function and it is possible that file names might be mapped to upper or lower case."

Comment: You could  loop through the return value of  `list.files` (while using tolower) and check so if a file exists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggested solution using `list.files`:

If we have many files we might want to do this only once, otherwise we can put in in the function (and pass `path_to_root_directory` instead of `found_files` to the function)

```
  found_files <- list.files(path_to_root_directory, recursive=FALSE)
```

Behaviour as `file.exists` (return value is boolean):

```
  fileExIsTs <- function(file_path, found_files) {
    return(tolower(file_path) %in% tolower(found_files))
  }
```

Return value is file with spelling as found in directory or `character(0)` if no match:

```
  fileExIsTs <- function(file_path, found_files) {
    return(found_files[tolower(found_files) %in% tolower(file_path)])
  }
```

## Edit:

New solution to fit new requirements:

```
keywordExists <- function(keyword, found_files) {
  return(any(grepl(keyword, found_files, ignore.case=TRUE)))
}

keywordExists("NaMe", found_files=c("filename.csv", "morefilenames.csv"))
```

Returns:

```
[1] TRUE
```

**Or**
Return value are files with spelling as found in directory or `character(0)` if no match:

```
keywordExists2 <- function(file_path, found_files) {
  return(found_files[grepl(keyword, found_files, ignore.case=TRUE)])
}

keywordExists2("NaMe", found_files=c("filename.csv", "morefilenames.csv"))
```

Returns:

```
[1] "filename.csv"      "morefilenames.csv"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, your function seems to need an identical match to work. i need to know if a filename contains a string, lowercase or uppercase. so if i'm testing for "name", i need to get TRUE for "filename.csv", "morefilenames.csv" etc.

Comment: Well then your problem is not lower or upper case of filenames but that you want to match **any** filename that has a string appearing in it?! And do you need only a TRUE or FALSE or do you want the list of **all** matches?? (see my edit above)

Answer (score -1):

The following should return a 1 if the filename matches in any case and a 0 if it does not.

```
max(grepl("*name*",list.files()),ignore.case=T)
```

Comment: I am specifically looking for case **insensitive** matching.